# What are the problems with using SVG today?

Tags: svg

I noticed https://beta.icloud.com/ didn't use SVG which surprised me. Here Apple is on the cutting-edge using things like background: -webkit-canvas(animation) and they're not using SVG on what seems like a perfect place to use it. I want to delve deep into SVG but before I do I want to understand its limitations. When I see demos like [this Mozilla demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/demos/detail/browser-usage-plurality/launch) it doesn't seem like it has major problems. What would be the reasons a large corporation, for example, would not use SVG?

Comment: Why should they be using SVG? Those images don't seem particular friendly to vector graphics. You do understand the difference between vector and raster graphics, right? If not, turn the question into that, it's less likely to be closed.

Comment: Why wouldn't an icon be particularly friendly to vector graphics? Wouldn't you want an icon to be sharp when scaled to any resolution? Apple's devices have viewport resolutions that span the whole spectrum from very small to very large. Furthermore, the graphics can be managed and manipulated (e.g. transition/animation effects) on the frontend and don't require changes from graphic designers.

Comment: How would you describe the details in those icons (e.g. the clouds behind the envelope, the world map behind the radar, the vein of the wooden surface, etc.) in SVG? Moreover, how would you do so without making the SVG file significantly larger than a raster image for the largest resolution anticipated?

Comment: I don't know. So are you saying SVG doesn't support SVG texture maps? I'm no expert but it looks like it does: http://nathanw.net/2013/05/02/svg-textures-in-qgis/ Are the file sizes so much larger (after compression of course) that the tradeoffs of SVG (or SVGz) compared to raster images are not worthwhile? They look pretty good.

Comment: A texture map is just a complicated kind of bitmap, with the same limitations.  Maybe on the margins you can get slightly better image quality at a particular file size, but is it worth the effort?

Comment: In these icons, having slightly pixilated rasters at high resolution wouldn't look bad. I think the tradeoff of having sharp icons at large scale and not depending on the designers for everything is worthwhile.

Answer (score 3):

There are relatively few "problems" with using SVG today. For the most part, it's a question of fit and familiarity - there are a lot of problems where the solution is to dynamically draw to a raster buffer. That is, `canvas`.

However, for Apple, the problem is that Safari has the worst of SVG compatibility of any major browser (at least, the last time I tested it). They want their sites to work in Safari.

Comment: Yeah, Canvas would be better for dynamic raster redraws. So in your last experiments with Safari, SVG didn't work too well. How long ago was that?

Comment: @Dathan SVG generally works well in most browsers. Last time I played with SVG was over a year ago. I use SVG for resizable arrows on this page: http://tustinincorporations.com/. As much as anything, the issue is handling minor inconsistencies.

Comment: Cool, looks good. There are always minor inconsistencies in HTML, I don't know of any showstoppers with using SVG today.

Comment: @Dathan Feel free to upvote any answers you find helpful ;)

Comment: Sorry, new here. Thanks for your help.